# Extract a part of a dictionnary file

Tags: python, json

Before saying I didn't search for an answer, I did and even if i'm not a Python expert, I didn't find any explicit answer.
For me to be clear, I'd like to extract 2 infos ("name" & "fame") from a specific "clan".
In the json file extracted, the info are on [items] then in [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHKO.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kTSm.png) and [3] and [4]. In this dictionnary on [standings]. Then, my issue is in the next dictionnary, it can be or in [0] or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHKO.png) or [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kTSm.png) or [3] or [4]. I don't know how to filter, for exemple by using something like "filter with tag = #9VL9L9Y".
Here is my code:

```
    data = json.loads(response)

    for item in data ["items"]:
        for p in item ["standings"]:
                for q in p ["clan"]["participants"]:
                    if (p["clan"] = '#9VL9L9YQ'):
                        print("%s %s" % (
                            q["name"],
                            q["fame"],

))
```

I know my line "if (p["clan"] = '#9VL9L9YQ'):" is not correct but this is what i'd like to do.

How the JSON file looks like:

### [image]

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: if p["clan"] == '#9VL9L9YQ':

Should be the line if u want to check if that entry of the array is equal to the given string

Comment: you should post the json as text - if someone wanted to help you they should have the possibility to test their code by copy-pasting the input...

Comment: I can't add the full json file, too many characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder the logic a bit:

```
data = json.loads(response)

for item in data ["items"]:
    for p in item ["standings"]:
        clan = p["clan"]
        # check tag first:
        if clan["tag"] == '#9VL9L9YQ': # remove extraneous )
            for q in clan["participants"]:
                print("%s %s" % (q["name"], ["fame"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code, simply correct it:

### Replace:

```
if (p["clan"] = '#9VL9L9YQ'):
```

### With:

```
if (p["clan"] == '#9VL9L9YQ'):
```

**Note**: your syntax was almost correct you just had a small and common mistake to forget using double "=" for comparison.